# How to print full presenter notes without slides in Keynote

Tags: keynote

I have a 50 slide presentation with extensive notes, and urgently need to print out those notes.

Keynote 6 appears to offer no way to do this.  All print options include slides, and/or do not print the full notes.  Any notes that exceed one page, will simply be truncated from the printout.

Is there any way to copy/paste, export, or print the presenter note text in full, without (or even with at this point!) the slides?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This applescript should do it for you:

```
global presenterNotes
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    open (choose file)
    tell front document
        set presenterNotes to presenter notes of every slide as text
            set the clipboard to presenterNotes
        do shell script "pbpaste > ~/keynote-notes.txt"
    end tell    
    quit application "Keynote"
end tell
```

Comment: Interesting... I'm long past needing to do this, but the next time I have occasion to do so, I'll give this a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: All good, yes I thought given some of your other questions you would have already written the script yourself. Just added it for completeness, plus it was fun to write.

Comment: Works perfectly as of 05/2016! Thanks @Deesbek!

Comment: Needed this today (October 2017). Worked brilliantly. Thanks!

Comment: Worked great today. I wonder how to add carriage returns between slide notes, and perhaps number them with the slide number before each set of notes.

Comment: Verified as functional today on a fully-patched Mojave machine with the current release of Keynote. Great work - Thank you!

Comment: How do you run this script?

Comment: Still works like a charm on a Mojave machine. Just open script editor on the Mac, paste the script above, and hit the "play" button on the top. The script will dump the .txt file in the root of your user directory with the name "keynote-notes.txt".

Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Here is a enhanced version with page num export: https://gist.github.com/boillodmanuel/1f4b94f0410081338a98935f13c557da

Comment: Confirming this still works in 2022, hooray!  (One way to run AppleScript -- took me a bit to figure out -- is using the "Automator" application, creating a workflow, and selecting "run AppleScript". There may be an easier way but that's the one I found)

Comment: It still works in December 2023. I created a modified version to add slide numbers and copy the result to the clipboard without intermediate files: https://gist.github.com/noe/3fb2bdb55b624f8baabb6a2d523f6481

Comment: Very glad it still works @noe, thanks for the improvements !!!!